# Fuse for gauge and button lights in Toyota Sienna

Tags: toyota, lights, fuse, sienna

When I turn on the head lights in my 2014 Toyota Sienna LE, the gauge lights, AC button lights in the front and the second row no longer turn on. Lights such as tire pressure low indicator, maintenance, etc. still turn on. I think this is happening because of a blown fuse, but I can't find the fuse in the owner's manual. Which fuse controls these lights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the dimmer knob hasn't been accidentally turned all the way down?  Try adjusting the dimmer;  twist the trip odometer reset stick.

Comment: That was it. On other cars I've seen that knob being used to reset the trip odometer, not to also control the LED lights. I thought it was odd that the light LED fuses I had pulled out all looked OK.